# Problem installing SSL on centos 5.2 with plesk

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl

I'm trying to install an ssl certificate to a dedicated centos 5.2 server. I followed the hosting company's instructions but the ssl is not working.

When I try to access my website using https, Firefox gives the following error:

> uses an invalid security certificate.
>   The certificate expired on 3/13/2010 11:56 AM.
>   (Error code: sec_error_expired_certificate)

I'm not sure where the problem is. You should also know that this server has plesk installed, even though I'm not using it, it could potentially be somehow overriding my httpd.conf or ssl.conf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in your Apache logs, especially error.log and access.log?  Those will be your biggest clues as to what is wrong.

Plesk does have the ability to manage httpd.conf and ssl.conf files, and sets things up a certain way.  You say you're not using it -- why is it installed, then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the linux environment. The server came plesk pre-installed. I never used it so far. All my web documents are in a folder called default under a directory called vhosts.

I can uninstall plesk, but I'm afraid it would bring down my website.

My server does not have any files named error.log or access.log.

Comment: The problem was plesk. I created the domain under plesk and associated the certificate with the domain. Now it is working.